# Control ServiceStack deserialization of POST variable and store in object

Tags: c#, serialization, servicestack, servicestack-text

I would like to deserialize a post variable using ServiceStack's built in deserialization.  But, I would like to make two changes that will provide me with some flexibility for another problem that I am attempting to solve.

`[Route("/MyObject/{Property}", "POST")]
    OtherRoutes...
    public class MyObject:IReturn<MyObjectResponse>{
        public string Property{ get; set; }
        public object Dto{ get; set; }
        Other properties...
    }
    public class CommodityType{
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public string CommodityTypeName{ get; set; }
    }`

If the post variable class name matches {Property}, I want to create that DTO class and store that in the Dto object.  I want everything else to deserialize normally.

For example if I post to: "example.com/API/MyObject/CommodityType"
the following json:

`{
    "CommodityType":{
        "Id": 1,
        "CommodityTypeName": "Commercial Services"
    }
}`

`if(MyObject.Property == POST.ObjectName){
    // in this example Post.ObjectName = "CommodityType"
    // Use Reflection to create object of type MyObject.Property
    // Deserialize into the object created by reflection
    // MyObject.Dto = Deserialized object
}`

Is this a situation where I could use Request and Response filters?
Should I create a custom request binder?
Is there another way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's an option, but from your example I would be including a property for `CommodityType` with the type that you want to deserialize into so the JSON Serializer can populate it for you, e.g:

```
public Request
{
    public CommodityType CommodityType { get; set; }
}
```

It's ok if it doesn't exist as it will just be left as `null`.

Depending on the shape of the Request DTO property, another option might be to make the dynamic part an `object` and Configure ServiceStack's JSON Serializer to convert object types to string Dictionary, e.g:

```
JsConfig.ConvertObjectTypesIntoStringDictionary = true; // in AppHost

public Request
{
    public object CommodityType { get; set; }
}
```

In which case `object` will be deserialized into a loose-typed Dictionary, which you can inspect change it to a strong type in your Request Filter.

Otherwise if you want to further change the default deserialization behavior, you'll need to use a [Custom Request Binder](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization#create-a-custom-request-dto-binder) and handle custom deserialization and handle the deserialization yourself.

ServiceStack.Text includes support for parsing arbitrary JSON with `JsonObject` API's, see links in [Custom Deserialization](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text#custom-deserialization) for some examples.

Comment: It sounds like the second option is what I will need to do.  Would it be possible for you to clarify, "In which case object will be deserialized into a loose-typed Dictionary, which you can inspect change it to a strong type in your Request Filter." in particular the "which you can inspect change it to a strong type in your Request Filter"

Comment: Without any `__type` info, ServiceStack has no way of determining what type an `object` property should be deserialized into which is why `object` properties are left as a `string` by default. This can be changed with `JsConfig.ConvertObjectTypesIntoStringDictionary = true` to deserialize it into a `Dictionary<string,string>`.  Changing it into a strong type just means replacing the dictionary with your own object instance which you can do here since it's an `object` property so it can be set to any instance.